# Is there a simple CLI command to copy just the speed of a SELECT statement into a text file (without the data) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

Let's say I run:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 AS
SELECT ssn, title
FROM employees
WHERE title = "Dictator"
```

I want to automatically save into a text file:

```
Query OK, 1118933 rows affected (3.84 sec)
Records: 1118933  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Bonus points if you can also save the query above it :)!

```
CREATE TABLE t1 AS
SELECT ssn, title
FROM employees
WHERE title = "Dictator"

Query OK, 1118933 rows affected (3.84 sec)
Records: 1118933  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: What is the used operating system?

Comment: Good point! In this case MacOS. However, I would also be curious to know other systems as well. May benefit the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `tee` builtin command in the mysql client.

I tested this on MacOS:

```
mysql> tee out
Logging to file 'out'

mysql> create table test.mytable as select sleep(2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (2.09 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> exit;
Bye

$ cat out
mysql> create table test.mytable as select sleep(2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (2.09 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> In this case MacOS. However, I would also be curious to know other
>   systems as well. May benefit the community.

The tee command also works on Windows. 
Note you need to use the complete path and the file needs to be created

```
mysql> tee C:/out.txt
Logging to file 'C:/out.txt'
mysql> select * from stackoverflow.newtable;
+---------+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
| Data1   | Data3   | Data5   |
| Data2   | Data4   | Data6   |
| 1       | 2       | NULL    |
| 1       | 2       | NULL    |
| 2       | 1       | NULL    |
+---------+---------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Content off C:/out.txt

```
mysql> select * from stackoverflow.newtable;
+---------+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
| Data1   | Data3   | Data5   |
| Data2   | Data4   | Data6   |
| 1       | 2       | NULL    |
| 1       | 2       | NULL    |
| 2       | 1       | NULL    |
+---------+---------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```